# Function 'deg2rad' could not be resolved

Tags: c++

I am receiving an error because of the following code :

```
const double    angle = deg2rad(180);
```

The error says:

```
Function 'deg2rad' could not be resolved
```

I have recently installed 'Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers' and I have added -std=c++11 to Other flags at C/C++ Build/Settings/Tool Settings/GCC C++ Compiler/Miscellaneous

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm new in stack overflow. I don't understand why my question got 5 downvotes? I wanna know what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `deg2rad()` in the C++11 standard so, unless it's provided by some other library, you'll have to write your own. Something like this should do as a start:

```
double deg2rad (double degrees) {
    return degrees * 4.0 * atan (1.0) / 180.0;
}
```

---

As per the above code, I normally leave micro-optimisations up to the compiler, such as letting it decide whether short functions should be inlined, or whether it will constant-fold the expression `4.0 * atan (1.0) / 180.0` into a single constant.

However, there may be a case in certain circumstances (such as if the compiler isn't as clever as the ones I use) to explicitly add the optimisations (keeping in mind that `inline` is a suggestion to the compiler rather than a demand):

```
inline double deg2rad (double degrees) {
    static const double pi_on_180 = 4.0 * atan (1.0) / 180.0;
    return degrees * pi_on_180;
}
```

Comment: My apology, I didn't know that There is no deg2rad() in the C++11 standard. The solution completely worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard library does not include a `deg2rad` function. You will need to create your own, or include a library which has one. An example of such a function is:

```
#include <cmath>

double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return deg * M_PI / 180.0;
}
```

Note that M_PI is not actually part of the standard either, but is commonly included in the `cmath` header. If you are using Visual C++ you will need to define `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` to enable it.

Comment: If `M_PI`  is not defined, an alternative is to compute it using basic approaches, such as `4.0*atan(1.0)` or `atan2(0.0, -1.0)`.   If the value is needed frequently, calculate it once, and store it in a variable for later use.

Comment: @Peter if `M_PI` is not defined I would suggest finding a new compiler... because at that point you probably have bigger issues than missing constants.

Comment: Thanks. M_PI is not defined so I used basic approach that you suggested.

Comment: @Mgetz - `M_PI` is not standard., as ajshort mentioned  Omitting something that is not required does not indicate any problem with the compiler, or the implementation of the library.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not implement a `deg2rad` function, so you will need to write it by yourself.

```
inline double deg2rad(double deg)
{
    return deg * M_PI / 180.;
}
```

Notice how we declare the function `inline`: This is because we don't want to waste extra assembly instructions setting up the call stack and jumping to the address of the function. When the function is inlined, it is substituted into the place it was called from. Note that `inline` is just advice to the compiler, and it is free to ignore it.